# How to redirect with nginx to an url with file extensions

Tags: nginx

what i have written so far in the config looks like the following:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name www.thissouldberedirected.com;
     rewrite ^ http://www.example.de/nice/stillnice/nice.html permanent;
}
```

The result is http://www.example.de/nice/stillnice/nice.html/ which causes page not found...

what i need is http://www.example.de/nice/stillnice/nice.html

Comment: where's the config of the other server, the `example.de`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that i'm using to make a php file to convert like directory

```
rewrite ^/test/$ /test.php last;
```

**Before : example.com/test.php**

**after example.com/test/**

**what u are looking is 301 redirect**

```
if ( $request_filename ~ old-page/ ) {
      rewrite ^ http://newdomain/next-best-page/? permanent;
   }
```

source: https://jeffsebring.com/2012/nginx-301-redirects/